# How can I make text to be changed AFTER the div is finally fades in (JS, jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript  function, that writes a text inside a div in html document (using inneHTMLr). This function also have jQuery function, that slowly makes this div unvisible - `$("#descr").fadeOut();`, and then visible - `$("#descr").fadeIn();` before writing text in it.

I can call this function several times, giving it different texts to write. But since the "fade out" and "fade in" effects are slow, i see the text change inside the div, before it fades out and fades in again.

How can I make text to be changed after the div is finally fades in?
I would be grateful for the easiest way.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var name1 = "name";
  var name2 = "3";
  var name3 = "Text that I want to write";

  function start() {

    $("#here").fadeOut();
    $("#here").fadeIn();
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = eval(name1 + name2);
  }
 function start2() {

    $("#here").fadeOut(600);
    $("#here").fadeIn(600);
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = "New text";
  }
</script>

<div id="here" style="background-color: green; color: white; display: none;"></div>

<button onclick="start()">
  Text-1
</button>

<button onclick="start2()">
  Text-2
</button>
```

P.S. I used two functions here, but in my project I have only one but more complicated function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the fadeIn/fadeOut a callback functions as such:

```
$("#ele").fadeIn(200, function() {
  //code after 200ms
});
```

Check out [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) for more info!

Comment: np! happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the text change and `fadeIn` inside a callback function of the fadeOut instruction *so that they only will run after the fadeOut has completed*:

```js
  var name1 = "name";
  var name2 = "3";
  var name3 = "Text that I want to write";

  function start() {

    $("#here").fadeOut(500, function(){
       $('#here').html(name1 + name2);
       $("#here").fadeIn();
    });
  }
 function start2() {

    $("#here").fadeOut(600, function(){
       $('#here').html("New text");
       $("#here").fadeIn(600);
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="here" style="background-color: green; color: white; display: none;"></div>

<button onclick="start()">
  Start
</button>

<button onclick="start2()">
  Start
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And thank you for illustration, how is it possible to write using jQery, part of this function, which uses innerHTML!